# Heroku App keeps crashing according to logs... why?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, crash

As soon as I deployed the app and pushed up the code from this tutorial: 
http://blog.superpat.com/2011/06/14/node-js-chat-demo-on-heroku/

I received this error from heroku: 
"An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

Here's the log error I'm getting:

```
2013-05-07T12:46:21.537628+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2013-05-07T12:46:21.537946+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2013-05-07T12:46:21.538118+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'pg'
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:380:17)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:22:10)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540462+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
2013-05-07T12:46:21.540143+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
2013-05-07T12:46:22.755998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-05-07T12:47:21.212523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=nodechatclient.herokuapp.com fwd="72.229.150.213" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-05-07T12:47:22.593111+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=nodechatclient.herokuapp.com fwd="72.229.150.213" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I followed all the code from that tutorials' github.

What could be causing it? Does it have something to do with pg? Was I supposed to change the database path somewhere?

When I try to run it locally using node server.js, however I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module    '/home/euridice/node_modules/pg/lib/native/../../build/default/binding'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/euridice/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:16:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

What does that mean?

EDIT: Fixed a few things and now I'm getting:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

at Connection.<anonymous>    (/home/euridice/node_chat/node_modules/pg/lib/native/index.js:187:17)
at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Comment: This smells like you don't have the PG module installed as a dependency in your app.

Comment: Persistence was added to the chat server as a later step.  Did you add a postgres as a dependency in the package.json file?  There is an example of how to do this later on in the original blog post, although I suggest using version 1.1.0 for postgres (rather than version 0.5 given in the blog post).  Thanks

Comment: @JR0cket, No I didn't. I suppose I look out for it. See my edit. Where do I find the instructions for adding postgres as a dependency? I can't find it.

Comment: Actually, it says: "Adding shared-database on nodechatclient... failed
 !    Add-on not found.
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run

```
npm install
```

locally, and also push the "node_modules" folder to heroku

**EDIT:** i think you misunderstood some git and herkoku concepts. you need to:

```
1. clone the repository: 'git clone git://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/node_chat.git'
2. go into the repository: 'cd node_chat'
3. now you can run 'npm install' in THAT folder
4. after that you can create your heroku app: 'heroku create'
5. and deploy that to heroku: 
  5.1 git add .
  5.2 git commit -m "some comment"
  5.3 git push heroku master
```

you MUST a) be in your node_chat folder, b) first npm install, and then push EVERYTHING (git add .) into heroku!

Comment: "npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/euridice/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-27-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/euridice
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path /home/euridice/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! not ok code 0"

Comment: That's what I get when I run npm install.

Comment: Also, git push node_modules
fatal: 'node_modules' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly